# how to enable tracking of links in chatbase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am writing a bot in telegrams (pytelegrambotapi), how to enable link tracking in chatbase for analytics. there is a link to their documentation I can not understand what code I need to write to the bot.

[ChatBase](https://chatbase.com/documentation/taps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second option given in chatbase [documentation](https://chatbase.com/documentation/taps):

Just make your URL with the given format and replace the link where you are using it for tracking.

https://chatbase.com/r?api_key=your_api_key&url=your_website_url

for example, my website URL is https://abc1345.com and api_key is "12343554" then my URL will be as follows:

https://chatbase.com/r?api_key=12343554&url=https://abc1345.com

Note: Metrics will update on the dashboard after 6 hours as per the documentation